# qemu - Could not initialize SDL(No available video device)

Tags: windows-10, qemu

I am trying to open an img file on qemu that works fine with `qemu-nox` but not when I use `qemu-system-i386` and the error I am met with is the following

```
qemu-system-i386 -serial mon:stdio -drive file=fs.img,index=1,media=disk,format=raw -drive file=xv6.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -smp 2 -m 512
Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting
```

I am using Windows 10 with the Linux subsystem.

Any suggestions as to how to make this run in graphics mode?

Comment: Refer to this article: https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx